# Using await Task<T> async hangs controller in MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I have two MVC websites.  Site 1 has a controller that calls Site 2 with the following code

```
 //  If I remove this in the controller of site1, then execution continues....
 var asdf =   SharedTypes.Utilities.GetjsonStream("http://localhost:11541/UIDP/Details/a1?format=json");
 string g =  asdf.Result;


public class Utilities
{
    public static async Task<string> GetjsonStream(string url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("Content: " + content);
        return content;
    }
}
```

I'm able to directly browse the URL and see the JSON.. but what is the correct way to download JSON from my peer website in MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably turn the controller method into an `async` method and use `await` to [avoid deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyActionAsync()
{
    var asdf = SharedTypes.Utilities.GetjsonStream(someUrl);
    string g = await asdf;
    // return something
}
```

Microsoft's ASP.NET tutorial includes a page on [async methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

Comment: This seems to work well for one project calling another... but I couldn't get it to work for a MVC app to use HTTPWebRequest to call itself.  It was probably unneeded overhead anyway.  This is great for the two sites communicating with each other ...