# ajax Json response received as HTML instead of json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an application which works fine on my localhost. But as soon as i access it from a different machine, it doesnt work as expected.

I have a following ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: rootUrl + 'ro/createRO',
    data: JSON.stringify(postdata),
    success: function (RoCreateResult) {
        /
        if (allRowsSelected) {
            window.location = rootUrl + "ro/RoPendingSummary?RoNumber=" + RoCreateResult.roNumber;
        } else {
            _AE.successAlert("RO " + RoCreateResult.roNumber + " created successfully");
            refreshRoPendingGrid();
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {

        var errobj = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        _AE.errorAlert(errobj.message);
    }
});
```

This is working fine on success.
But on failure, xhr.responseText that i get is in json format(which is expected) but when accessed from another machine, it gives a HTML format. What could be the possible reason for this behaviour?

The Expected JSON is

```
message:"This operation cannot be completed because it will result in budget overshoot for the following estimates"

The HTML that it returns is:<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0       Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-    family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-        top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it     cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Code which generates exception

```
public async static Task<RoCreateResult> CreateRO(int[] estItemIds)
    {

        using (DDb db = new DDb())
        {
            RoCreateResult roData = await db.Database.SqlQuery<RoCreateResult>(
                "s_roCreate")
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            return roData;
        }
    }
```

Things i tried:
1. Tried to use jsonp instead of json - Didnt work.
2. Installed the package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors 5.2.3 and added the HTTPconfiguration to enable CORS. - Failed.

Is there anything else which I can try?

Comment: What do you see on failure? What kind of failure are we talking about here? Is it possible that in case of "failure", the service does not reach the layer of code (server) that is capable of returning json but the response is generated by a "default" handler?

Comment: what is the html tht is returned in case of failure? are you sure the response is not an error page being returned? like a default 404 page?

Comment: What does `rootUrl` contain?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao rootUrl has value "http://localhost/application" if i access it from localhost

Comment: </head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Remove the `rootUrl` and just keep `url: '/ro/createRO'` and what it will have if you access it from server? because there is no `/` between rootUrl and `ro/createRo`

Comment: @KnightFox The error it returns is a 500 error.

Comment: The error is thrown by database due to some validation constraints. The valid error message has to be 
message:"This operation cannot be completed because it will result in budget overshoot for the following estimates". Instead it wraps this message inside an html and send back

Comment: show the server side code instead!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - rootUrl works fine. all / has already been taken care of.

Comment: Alright then we need to see server side code cs that's where you have information of handling errors and sending it back!

Comment: you are sending the xhtml page from application server when there is error.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - the following is the place from where error is thrown from the database and being returned.
 public async static Task<RoCreateResult> CreateRO(int[] estItemIds)
  {
  
   using (DDb db = new DDb())
   {
    RoCreateResult roData = await db.Database.SqlQuery<RoCreateResult>(
     "s_roCreate")
     .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    return roData;
   }
  }

Comment: @Panther - i get a json format error message when i access it from my localhost

Comment: Sinu! I suggest you to handle the errors depending on the various possibilities and return `json` data everytime from server method as you are expecting the same from your `ajax` call!

Comment: Yes, because there may be some difference in your server configuration on local and remoter server. Either your application server or webserver sending the error page. More chances webserver

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - Let me try that. I'll get back to you in a moment

Comment: @GuruprasadRao. i tried putting the await statement in a try block and tried to debug. But after exception has occured, it doesnt even go to catch block

Comment: Are you handling like **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20227579/2065039)**?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - yes I'm using an await .
 RoCreateResult roData = await db.Database.SqlQuery<RoCreateResult>(
                "s_roCreate")
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Comment: To be honest I am not very much familiar with `async` and `await` but what I feel is your `return` should be something like `return Json(data)`. A sample, might not be exact one!

Answer (score 2):

The HTML that returned to you says

### 500 - Internal server error.

#### There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it     cannot be displayed.

which means, there is an error on the server side for the request that you are trying to access (could be a code that is throwing exception). you need to wrap the code in your server side language using try..catch and log the error to db or return the error in your json format. ie message : the error that you have catched from your code. this is not related to your javascript code.

Comment: i tried to use try catch. But an exception raised by database doesnt get caught in a catch block

Comment: I didn't see any try catch in the code you have commented
public async static Task<RoCreateResult> CreateRO(int[] estItemIds)
    {

        using (DDb db = new DDb())
        {
            RoCreateResult roData = await db.Database.SqlQuery<RoCreateResult>(
                "s_roCreate")
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            return roData;
        }
    }

Either give the try catch here or inside the function that calls this function. you will get it in any of the mentioned areas

Comment: let me explain :
Suppose you are calling the said method from another function called ExecuteCreateRO :

public static void ExecuteCreateRO(){
      try{
               CreateRO()

       }catch(Exception ex){
               //log or return exeption message
      }


this will catch the exception. act according to it