# Application hangs when sending from MVC Web Application to Azure IoT Hub Device

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-web-app-service, iot, azure-iot-hub

This is a controller code of an Azure Web App that handles a device notification logic. What I'm doing is invoking the code shown below from a ASP MVC Controller. But when I run it I get an ever-pending request from the browser(it hangs).
I have a button on view, when clicked, it invokes Wakeup method in the controller.

The code is not different from the one on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-c2d) for a console application. What am I missing?

```
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;

 public class MyTemplate2Controller : Controller
    {
        static ServiceClient serviceClient;
        static string connectionString = "HostName=azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=iothub;SharedAccessKey=mrUPt*2318C18K3LUk+oFarkNQ4vRvHrOa/eg=";

        private AsyncController Task SendCloudToDeviceMessageAsync()
        {
            var asd = "{13A20041677B0,4,15,0}";
            var commandMessage = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(asd));
          return  await serviceClient.SendAsync("Test_Comp_Dev_1", commandMessage).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
        }
        public void Wakeup()
        {

            serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

            SendCloudToDeviceMessageAsync().Wait();
        }
```

Comment: This question is too general, I recommend you try and do a remote debugging session to see where exactly your code is failing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
    public void Wakeup()
    {
        serviceClient = ServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(a => SendCloudToDeviceMessageAsync().Wait());
    }
```

Comment: The problem was in the await deadlock inside of the sync method. Using the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem was a quick workaround to yield the method. The better solution is to use an Asynchronous Controller, see more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227401/using-await-taskt-async-hangs-controller-in-mvc-app