# Send messages to IoTHuB in loop

Tags: uwp, arduino, async-await, azure-iot-hub, windows-iot-core-10

I am trying to develop a UWP app that will run on Windows IoT core. This app will read some sensor data coming from Arduino, then send it as a message to my azure iothub. I have been using async methods in the code.

```
private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
        Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;
        uint ReadBufferLength = 1024;
        // If task cancellation was requested, comply
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        // Set InputStreamOptions to complete the asynchronous read operation when one or more bytes is available
        dataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
        using (var childCancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken))
        {
            // Create a task object to wait for data on the serialPort.InputStream
            loadAsyncTask = dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(childCancellationTokenSource.Token);
            // Launch the task and wait
            UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                var tempData = dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
                rcvdText.Text = tempData;
                status.Text = "bytes read successfully!";
                await SendDeviceToCloudMessagesAsync(tempData);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Definition of SendDeviceToCloudMessagesAsync :**

```
private async Task SendDeviceToCloudMessagesAsync(string data)
    {
        //do some string manipulations on data and create the telemetry object.

        deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(deviceConnString);

            var messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetry);
            var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));

            await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
     }
```

This is how the method is being called:

```
  // keep reading the serial input
  while (true)
  {
       await ReadAsync(ReadCancellationTokenSource.Token);
  }
```

The expectation here is that the application should keep on reading serial input, and send it to the iothub continuously in loop. But the problem is that it is executing only once, and then returns to the UI. If I remove the line await SendDeviceToCloudMessagesAsync(tempData), then the code continues to listen to serial input.So I understand it has something to do with the SendEventAsync method. I was able to use this method in loop in a .net console application but I am not sure how to fix it here in UWP.

**Below is the signature for SendEventAsync method(from metadata):**

```
public Task SendEventAsync(Message message);
```

I am fairly new to asynchronous programming. Any help would be appreciated.Please comment if I need to provide additional input in the question.

Answer (score 0):

you have a threading problem.
Try to use the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem for yielding a process to send a message.

Comment: I'm sorry could you be more specific? an example or reference will be helpful. Meanwhile I am looking for references online too.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061834/application-hangs-when-sending-from-mvc-web-application-to-azure-iot-hub-device?rq=1

Comment: I have come to realise that the await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message) works in a .net console applictaion, but does not in a UWP app. But then there must be some way to be able to call this method in a UWP app as well?

Comment: I was able to resolve this by changing the return type of SendEventAsync(message)'s caller to 'Task' instead of 'void'.