# SqlConnection closes unexpectedly inside using statement

Tags: c#, sql, parallel-processing

I have an SQL connection service that I'm trying to build. I essentially do this:

```
var data = await GetDataFromFlatFilesAsync(dir).ConfigureAwait(false);
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        var rw = new SqlReaderWriter(conn);

        await DoStuffWithSqlAsync(rw, data).ConfigureAwait(false);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         // Do exceptional stuff here
     }
}
```

`DoStuffWithSqlAsync` operates like this:

```
private async Task DoStuffWithSqlAsync(SqlReaderWriter rw, IEnumerable<Thing> data)
{
    await Task.WhenAll(data.Select(rw.RunQueryAsync)).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

And `RunQueryAsync` operates like this:

```
public async Task RunQueryAsync<T>(T content)
{
    // _conn is assigned to in the constructor with conn
    try
    {
        var dataQuery = _conn.CreateCommand();
        dataQuery.CommandText = TranslateContentToQuery(content);
        await dataQuery.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Do exceptional stuff here
    }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that `DoStuffWithSqlAsync` continuously fails with a `System.InvalidOperationException` stating that conn is in a closed state. However, when I examine the stack trace, I find execution is still inside the using statement. I also know that `conn` is not closed anywhere inside this operation as execution must necessarily return to the statement and any exception inside should be bubbled up to the enclosing try-catch and caught there. Additionally, the connection is pooled and MARS is enabled. So then, why is this being closed?

**UPDATE:** It was pointed out that I hadn't opened my connection. I have done so but the error persists except now `_conn.State` is set to `Open`.

**UPDATE:** I was having an issue wherein I used `await conn.OpenAsync.ConfigureAwait(false);` which would not block execution. So, when I tried to connect to the database, I would get an exception stating that the connection state was closed but by that point it would have opened so on examination it would show Open. It was suggested that I make the calling method async void but as the application is console, not UI I don't think that will help. I have since reverted to using the synchronous method.

Comment: Although you are using the `using` statement, you still have to open the connection. Have a look at [this article ("Open method call")](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection).

Comment: might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583792/dbconnection-open-works-but-dbconnection-openasync-doesnt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to open the connection:

```
try
{
  conn.Open() //<--add this
  var rw = new SqlReaderWriter(conn);
  await DoStuffWithSqlAsync(rw, data).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it. I had the `await OpenAsync();` line in there and it went missing when I refactored last >_<

Thanks so much!